# d3.js time format %b %e return null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datetime-format

I have read https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting and related stackoverflow posts, but cannot find answer.

I already have date in this format.

```
Mon Jan 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

But I want to convert them from "%Y-%m-%d" to "%b %e". I directly used

`var parse = d3.time.format("%b %e").parse` and it returns null. 
I found an old post says because input is not in correct format.

I also tried "2015-01-26" as input, still return null.
So how can I get format as "%b %e" from `Mon Jan 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800` (PST)?

Answer (score 0):

You have Mon Jan 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) as a string and want to convert it to a date object?

```
var someDate = new Date("Mon Jan 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)");
```

Or you have Mon Jan 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) as a date object and want to format as a string like %b %e?

```
var format = d3.time.format("%b %e");
format(someDate);
```

Or you have Mon Jan 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) as a string and you want it as a string like %b %e?

```
var someDate = new Date("Mon Jan 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)");
var format = d3.time.format("%b %e");
format(someDate);
```